# Graphing from df.pivot returns AttributeError when targeting index as x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Graphing time and temperature data across zones. Importing the csv and reformatting into a pivot table to build distinctive columns:

```
in: dfpiv2 = df.pivot(index = 'target_logtime', columns = 'valuekey', values = 'value') 

out: 

valuekey    5575    5579    5583    5587    5591    5599    5603    5607    5611    5615
target_logtime                                      
2016-02-01 00:00:00     22.87   21.87   19.68   18.18   10.43   19.93   18.93   19.00   19.18   19.62
2016-02-01 00:30:00     22.43   21.50   19.56   17.87   10.43   19.68   18.87   18.93   19.00   19.37
2016-02-01 01:00:00     22.18   21.25   19.43   17.62   10.43   19.50   18.81   18.87   18.81   19.12
2016-02-01 01:30:00     21.87   21.00   19.31   17.37   10.43   19.31   18.81   18.81   18.68   18.93
2016-02-01 02:00:00     21.68   20.75   19.18   17.18   10.37   19.12   18.75   18.75   18.50   18.75
```

All seems to work okay, however, my target_logtime column which I want to use on the x-axis seems to disappear:

```
in: dfpiv2.columns    
out: Int64Index([5575, 5579, 5583, 5587, 5591, 5599, 5603, 5607, 5611, 5615], dtype='int64', name='valuekey')
```

Which I think is the cause of...

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'target_logtime'
```

Here's the full code that I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('******.csv')
dfpiv2 = df.pivot(index = 'target_logtime', columns = 'valuekey', values = 'value') 
import plotly
plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='********', api_key='*******')
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

#import dataset


# define x and y
x = dfpiv2.target_logtime
y1 = dfpiv2[5575]

# create a trace
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x = x,
    y = y1,
    mode = 'lines',
    name = '5575'
)

data = [trace1]

py.iplot(data, filename='basiclinetest')
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: target_logtime is the index after the pivot. You can make it a normal column with reset_index()

Comment: How are you trying to plot the dataframe?

Comment: Many thanks for that @P.Tillmann, have reset the index and reassigned with: dfpiv3 = dfpiv2.reset_index(). This makes value_key appear again.

Comment: Plotting the df as a line chart @xg.plt.py. I ran into another issue, but seemed to be a rookie mistake:
**in**
x = dfpiv3.target_logtime
y1 = dfpiv3['5575']
y2 = dfpiv3['5579']
**out**
KeyError 5575 | FIX: **in** x = dfpiv3.target_logtime
y1 = dfpiv3[5575]
y2 = dfpiv3[5579] **out* line graph!

Comment: Directly with matplotlib or through pandas? I think that wothpandas if x is not specified, the index is used, so there is no need to reindex. Could you update this part of the code into the question?

Comment: Have updated @xg.plt.py. If I remove the x specification, it runs but I lose my x labeling (reverts to row number?). Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `x=dfpiv2.index`? Without the reindex

Comment: It works @xg.plt.py! Will update the answers, thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2):

The pivot table (dfpiv2) is being indexed by `target_logtime`, therefore, an error arose when trying to access it as a column. There are 2 ways to access these values.

## Reindex

The first way is to to reset the index and re-assign it to a column using `dfpiv3 = dfpiv2.reset_index()`.

Then, when checking the columns:

```
In: dfpiv3.columns
Out: Index(['target_logtime', 5575, 5579, 5583, 5587, 5591, 5599, 5603, 5607, 5611, 5615], dtype='object', name='valuekey')
```

Which allows use of `target_logtime` as the x-axis when plotting a line chart via plotly (because `target_logtime` exists again)

## Access the index values

It's also possible to avoid reseting the index  when graphing via plotly by setting the x as `index` rather than the desired column name:

```
x = dfpiv2.index
y1 = dfpiv2[5575]
```

Thanks P.Tillmann and xg.plt.py for their comments.